# How to Get ShellNew sub menu items

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I am working on an application in that I need to display the sub menu of "New" context menu. i.e. when we right click on the desktop, we get new context menu item, on clicking on new, we get "Folder", "shortcut", "Text Document" and etc.

My questions are-

1. Is there any API to Get List to sub menu of new?
2. Also is there any API to get sub menu of "Send To"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **New** and **Send To** menu items are simple shell extensions which implement the `IContextMenu(2,3)` interfaces.  The CLSID of the **New** shell extension is `{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}`, and the CLSID of the **Send To** shell extension is `{7BA4C740-9E81-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837}`. So you need to implement the host for `IContextMenu` interface.

1. Create one of the COM objects
2. Query it for `IContextMenu` and `IShellExtInit`
3. Call `IShellExtInit.Initialize()`
4. Create a temp menu
5. Call `IContextMenu.QueryContextMenu()`

In the temp menu, you will have all of the available commands.

1. To run a command call `IContextMenu.InvokeCommand()`.

A lot of details you can find in The [Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) blog:

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 1 - Initial foray](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/20/231739.aspx)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 2 - Displaying the context menu](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/22/232836.aspx)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 3 - Invocation location](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/23/233376.aspx)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 4 - Key context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/24/234113.aspx)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 5 - Handling menu messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/27/234739.aspx)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 6 - Displaying menu help](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/28/235242.aspx)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 7 - Invoking the default verb](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/30/236133.aspx)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 8 - Optimizing for the default command](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/01/236627.aspx)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 9 - Adding custom commands](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/04/237507.aspx)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 10 - Composite extensions - groundwork](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/06/238630.aspx)

[How to host an IContextMenu, part 11 - Composite extensions - composition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/07/239197.aspx)

Comment: it worked for me, thanks for the solution. On more question, once i click on any option(text, folder, short cut). it creates file, but it will not be in edit mode, i.e. on clicking on test file, it creates "New Text document.txt". user has to explicitly need to rename the item.

Comment: "New" shell extension is waiting that it is called from Windows Explorer and it has more integration with Explorer. Explorer provide a lot of interfaces like IShellView through IObjectWithSite interface of shell extension. And it allows to shell extension to call user friendly rename functionality.

Comment: Hi New worked fine, but when i created Send To, then on context menu Send to comes. but on clicking on send to display empty list. do i need to any changes to send to apart from New.

Comment: With which parameters do you call IShellExtInit.Initialize?

Comment: ShellExtInit->Initialize(NULL, _pdtobj, NULL); I initialized IdataObject

Comment: Do you call IContextMenu2::HandleMenuMsg or IContextMenu3::HandleMenuMsg2 with WM_INITMENUPOPUP?

Comment: it contains CFSTR_SHELLIDLIST, if possible can you give me a sample of IDataObject for send to.

Comment: Try create DataObject with SHCreateDataObject or CIDLData_CreateFromIDArray functions.

Comment: I create IDataObject using SHCreateDataObject API. but still it is not showing sub menu.

Comment: one more information, i am right clicking on virtual file. ie file does not exist on the disk.

Comment: It does not matter. In my answer on another question a screenshot of Send to menu of virtual file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22990080/how-to-addenable-standard-send-to-context-menu-option-in-a-namespace-extensi/22994132#22994132

Comment: Try to add CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR+CFSTR_FILECONTENTS formats in your DataObject.