# Namespace shell extension and "New" (ShellNew) menu entires

Tags: windows, com, windows-shell, shell-extensions

I'm writing NSE and I can't get the answers to the following questions:

1. Is there an easy way to show the standard "New" context submenu with all the same entires as for the normal file system folder? Or I have to add and process them manually?
2. How to show/use the system "New folder" button in the Explorer toolbar? Or again - I have to implement it myself?

I would like to use as much standard features as possible to have my NSE looks like the standard FS folder regardless of the Winsows version...

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052139/how-to-get-shellnew-sub-menu-items/23054694

2) You must implement it by yourself.

Comment: @Denis, thank you. 1) Yes, I've seen this answer. So there is no "magic flag" to show and make these entires work automatically... it's a pity :)